# Problems connecting to database in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Server=iraq\\sqlexpress ; Database=stats ; Trusted_Connection=True ;"
    Dim com As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    com.CommandText = "insert into users values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "')"
    com.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close ()
```

There are new events happen when i adjust the connection string

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\stats.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

show me error with    com.ExecuteNonQuery()

any suggestion ?

Comment: How can you expect anyone to help you if you don't even supply the error message?

Comment: Please read up on SQL Injection attacks, and never let code like this make it to production.

Comment: Do you know what [SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) is? See also: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't speak to your connection String. Looks rather arduous. Beyond that, I see a few problems:

A. This is the most obvious to me: Your INSERT statement is incorrect. Try THIS:

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (column_name_1, column_name_2, . . .) VALUES (value_1, value_2, . . .)
```

B. Extend the above, in keeping with the comments of others, and properly PARAMETERIZE your query. Further, make use of the Application Settings file for your connection string, instead of hardcoding it into your app. Last, employ a Using block, for the connection and command objects - this will handle initialization and Disposal of these. I stripped the following out of an old project of mine - hopefully I didn't muff any sytax adapting it for this post. The original code ran against a Stored Procedure in the SQL Server back-end:

```
Public Overridable Sub DataINSERT() Implements IAppUser.DataINSERT 'tblAppUser

    Dim CommandText As String = "INSERT INTO tblUser(UserName, PassWord, Enabled) VALUES(@UserName, @PassWord, @Active)"

    'The Connection String can be established in your Project Settings file:
    Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.MyDataConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(CommandText, cn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            'INSERT PARAMETER SET_UP:
            Dim prmUserName As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
            prmUserName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            prmUserName.Value = _UserName
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prmUserName)

            Dim prmPassWord As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@PassWord", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
            prmPassWord.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            prmPassWord.Value = _PassWord
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prmPassWord)

            Dim prmActive As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit, 0)
            prmActive.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            prmActive.Value = _Active
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prmActive)

            Try
                cn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim str As String = Me.ToString & ": " & ex.Message & " / " & ex.TargetSite.ToString
                MsgBox(str)
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub 'DataINSERT tblAppUser
```

My final comment would be to check out Stored Procedures with SQL Server. Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.